# perl split array into smaller arrays using the difference between values

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array

```
my @stuff = (6.5,6.54,6.465,6.3,6.42,8.07370,8.1165,8.07612,7.61855,6.94927,6.94072,8.09707,6.94468,7.55948,6.93,7.51448,8.02872,6.89643,7.44893,6.92997,7.46780,7.96705,6.93785,6.928,7.51177,7.93443,6.92620,7.40470,7.90602,8.39247,6.95032,7.42932,7.917,6.95272,7.93688,8.42192,6.95255,7.45207,8.43418,7.42768,8.42152,6.9645);
```

I want to divide this into a smaller arrays where  similar numbers can be grouped together without specifying the number of arrays. I want the values within each smaller array should not be more than 0.5 apart.

Comment: I assume that you do not care about the order in your data?

Comment: The wish is not enough, try something. I believe you can do that

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple one. Sounds like an assignment in a perl class.
I won't go into detail, but an easy solution would be, to sort the array. Then you iterate and check the difference between the current and the first element. As soon as your current element differs more than your delta (0.5) from the first, you split the array at this position. Then you start again with the shortened array.

There are many variations on how to do this. I am sure you will come up with a smart one.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @stuff = (6.5,6.54,6.465,6.3,6.42,8.07370,8.1165,8.07612,7.61855,6.94927,6.94072,8.09707,6.94468,7.55948,6.93,7.51448,8.02872,6.89643,7.44893,6.92997,7.46780,7.96705,6.93785,6.928,7.51177,7.93443,6.92620,7.40470,7.90602,8.39247,6.95032,7.42932,7.917,6.95272,7.93688,8.42192,6.95255,7.45207,8.43418,7.42768,8.42152,6.9645);
my (%h, @g);

my @r = map {
  my $el = $_;
  my ($ref) = map { abs($_-$el) <=0.5 ? $h{$_} : () } @g;

  if ($ref) { push @$ref, $_; }
  else {
    $h{$_} = [$_];
    push @g, $_;
  }
  $ref ? () : $h{$_};
}
sort { $a <=> $b }
@stuff;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@r;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        '6.3',
        '6.42',
        '6.465',
        '6.5',
        '6.54'
      ],
      [
        '6.89643',
        '6.9262',
        '6.928',
        '6.92997',
        '6.93',
        '6.93785',
        '6.94072',
        '6.94468',
        '6.94927',
        '6.95032',
        '6.95255',
        '6.95272',
        '6.9645'
      ],
      [
        '7.4047',
        '7.42768',
        '7.42932',
        '7.44893',
        '7.45207',
        '7.4678',
        '7.51177',
        '7.51448',
        '7.55948',
        '7.61855'
      ],
      [
        '7.90602',
        '7.917',
        '7.93443',
        '7.93688',
        '7.96705',
        '8.02872',
        '8.0737',
        '8.07612',
        '8.09707',
        '8.1165',
        '8.39247'
      ],
      [
        '8.42152',
        '8.42192',
        '8.43418'
      ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common clustering problem.
You should take a look at clustering algorithms like

[k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means) or [k-median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering) for the clustering part
and
[k-means++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means++) to get a good k (number of clusters)

Be aware that my suggestion is more complicated than the ones from the other answers, but if you'd like to dig deeper into such algorithms and need solutions for not only the 0.5 delta, these are some points to start.